# The tangent space of an almost complex manifold has a basis of a special form

Tags: smooth-manifolds, almost-complex

*An almost complex structure*  on a real differentiable manifold $M$ is a tensor field $J \in \Gamma(\mbox{End}(TM))$ satisfying $J^{2}=-I$, where $I$ is the identity tensor field. The pair $(M,J)$ is called an almost complex manifold.

> Question: Could someone show that each tangent space of $M$ has a basis of the form \begin{equation*}
> X_1, JX_1, \ldots, X_n, JX_n.
> \end{equation*}

We know $(\det J)^{2}=\det J^{2}=(-1)^{n} \Rightarrow n$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in M$, we have $J_x^=-Id_{T_xM}$, there exists a scalar product $b$ defines on $T_xM$ such that $b(J_x(u),J_x(v))=b(u,v)$ since the group generated by $J_x$ is finite. Let $u_1\in T_xM, u_1\neq 0$, the orthogonal $V_1$ of $Vect(u_1,J_x(u_2))$ is stable by $J_x$. Take $u_2,J_x(u_2)\in V_1, u_2\neq 0$, the orthogonal of $(u_1,J_x(u_1),u_2,J_x(u_2))$ is stable by $J_x$, recursively you obtain the basis.

Comment: I didn't understand why there exists this scalar product. However if that is satisfied then the conclusion is right.

Comment: One way is the following: Since $J^4 = id$, let $g$ be any inner product, then define $b(x, y) = g(x, y) + g(Jx, Jy) + g(J^2 x, J^2 y) + g(J^3x, J^3y)$. @mmath

Comment: In fact, it's enough to take $b(x, y) = g(x, y) + g(Jx, Jy)$.